# Excel - select a cell based on adjacent cell value

Tags: excel

I have the following excel spreadsheet and I am trying to work out how I can write a formula in order to provide the values in column D.

In each row, there is a test date, I am trying to calculate the day difference from each test date to the principal date, specific to each subject.

I assume this would involve selecting the principal test date based on the value in column C and I am not sure how I can do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
A            B           C                 D
Subject      TestDate    Principal date    Day difference from Principal  date
Subject 1    01/12/2014                    -3
Subject 1    02/12/2014                    -2
Subject 1    03/12/2014                    -1 
Subject 1    04/12/2014   Yes               0
Subject 2    07/12/2014                    -1
Subject 2    08/12/2014   Yes               0
Subject 2    11/12/2014                     3
Subject 3    17/12/2014                    -1
Subject 3    18/12/2014   Yes               0
Subject 3    24/12/2014                     6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic here is: (1) Find the date for each subject that is the principal date, and return it for each row; and (2) subtract this date from the current date in `col B`. (2) is easy, but (1) requires a way to match the value in `B` on both `Subject` and `Principal Date`. You can do this with an `INDEX-MATCH` function with multiple `MATCH` criteria.

With your data in `A2:C11` and the column headers in `row 1`, enter this formula in `D2` and fill down:

`{=B2-INDEX($A$2:$C$11,MATCH(1,($A$2:$A$11=$A2)*($C$2:$C$11="Yes"),0), 2)}`

Note that you need to enter it as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

The logic behind the `INDEX-MATCH` function is:

- `A2:C11` is your entire raw data table; the function looks over this entire table.

  - Note that you can include headers if you want, which can be useful in defining your lookup column by a matching column header name. If you do this, you need to make sure all of your arrays are of the same dimensions (*i.e.*, if your data table is `A1:C11`, your columns in the `MATCH` function need to start in `row 1` as well).
- The `MATCH` function looks for a value of `1` from the lookup array provided by multiplying multiple logical conditions. It will evaluate whether `A2=A2`, `A3=A2`, `A4=A2`, etc. and create a column of `TRUE`/`FALSE` values. It will then do the same for `C2="Yes"`, `C3="Yes"`, etc. The product of the logical arrays will be `1` any time both conditions are satisfied. (`0` tells `MATCH` to look for an *exact* match.)
- `2` tells the `INDEX` function to find the value in the second column (`B`) in the *row* specified by the `MATCH` function -- *i.e.*, where both conditions are met.

This value is then subtracted from the value in `B2` to give the date difference.

---

As noted in the comments, this formula can also be simplified to index only the desired lookup column:

`=B2-INDEX($B$2:$B$11,MATCH(1,($A$2:$A$11=$A2)*($C$2:$C$11="Yes"),0))`

Comment: Thank you so much for you help.  Just wondering why can't the formula be: =B2-INDEX($B$2:$B$11,MATCH(1,($A$2:$A$11=$A2)*($C$2:$C$11="Yes"),0)).    So the after index why does it have to be $A$2:$C$11 but not just $B$2:$B$11?

Comment: Good point. There is actually no reason in this case that it can't be `=B2-INDEX($B$2:$B$11,MATCH(1,($A$2:$A$11=$A2)*($C$2:$C$11="Yes"),0))`. In other circumstances, you may want the full array and column number argument (_e.g._, to specify the column number dynamically with something like `MATCH("ColName", RowHeaderArray, 0)`).

Answer (score 1):

Mostly the same logic as @Brendan's but slightly shorter.  This is still an array formula entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
=B2-SMALL(IF(IF($A$2:$A$11=A2,$C$2:$C$11)="Yes",$B$2:$B$11),1)
```

The inner `IF($A$2:$A$11=A2,$C$2:$C$11)` gets you an array with only the principal that corresponds to the subject your are in.  The next `IF(IF(...)="Yes",$B$2:$B$11)` gets you an array with only the principal date and FALSE for all other values.  `SMALL(...,1)` gets you just the principal date which you can subtract from the current test date: `B2-SMALL(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Extract the DAY() from your TestDate, and add the Day Difference:

Formula for column Principal date: =DAY(B2)+D2

```
     A           B           C                 D
1    Subject     TestDate    Principal date    Day difference from Principal
2    Subject 1   2014-06-01  28                -3
```

Now you have the correct day, and you can make a new date in a new column, or combine the two functions.